# How do I add space between an elements which is in flex-column?

Tags: html, css

I want to add some space between items in CSS , I tried many ways but didn't work.

I want this for hamburger menu, here is my CSS codes and HTML (note: I'm not pro!)

I have 3 a tags "Home" "Products" "About"
and I want to sort them like that.

Home

Products

About

but I couldn't add space between them (note: "side-item" class are child and "side-itemS" class is parent"

```css
.sidemenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
}

.side-items {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 8%;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
}

.side-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.side-item a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>ElectroLand</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <header>     
        <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <div class="logo"><img src="/img/logo.png"></div>
                    <div class="nav-list">
                        <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                        <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                        <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                        <div class="hamburger" onclick="clk()" id="burger">
                            <div id="line1"></div>
                            <div id="line2"></div>
                            <div id="line3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
           </div>
           <div class="sidemenu">
            <div class="side-items">
                <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <script src="/func.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: what do you wanna know?

Comment: We would like to see a [MRE] as SMAKSS says :) Take a look at the link we both have given you to see what that involves. But basically we can't help if we can't see the problem, and your CSS alone is not enough to show us what is happening.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and frameworks to it

Comment: How can I do? I really have a problem about using stackoverflow. I'm new

Comment: Just copy your html the same way you did for your css.

Comment: I did it. now look again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `justify-content : space-between` in `.side-items` with `height : 100%`.

**See the code below :**

```css
.sidemenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
}

.side-items {
  height:100%;
  justify-content:space-between;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 8%;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
}

.side-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.side-item a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>ElectroLand</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <header>     
        <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <div class="logo"><img src="/img/logo.png"></div>
                    <div class="nav-list">
                        <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                        <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                        <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                        <div class="hamburger" onclick="clk()" id="burger">
                            <div id="line1"></div>
                            <div id="line2"></div>
                            <div id="line3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
           </div>
           <div class="sidemenu">
            <div class="side-items">
                <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <script src="/func.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got 2 methods to solve my problem. thanks again

Comment: sorry but another question. Is there any way to increase side menu width?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `align-items : space-between` in `.side-items` css

Comment: You need to add some `height` to `.side-items` maybe you want it to be `height : 100vh`

Comment: @KevRob There is no point in trying to help any further until we get more information :) FYI it is actually discouraged to answer low quality questions that are unclear and need more details to be able to give a specific answer - see "Asked well-answered questions" in the help for ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for adding space between side menu items.

```
.side-item{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: padding must be empty?

Comment: @HaythamKenway This is why you need yo show us *exactly* what your code is doing  - otherwise all we can do is make wild guesses, and that is not an effective way to get a helpful answer!!

Comment: so how can I show the problem ? I just need some space between my items

Comment: "*so how can I show the problem ?*" By reading [ask], then see how to create a [MRE] and then edit your question with the *code you are using* so we can *see* it!!

Comment: @HaythamKenway you are using completely wrong approach to create a side menu bar, please use my [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/vamshidureddy/full/PoNxwQZ) sample for your reference.

Comment: @vamshidureddy what do you think about other parts of my code? I'm beginner but if you could give a point to my codes how much you would give from 10?

Comment: @HaythamKenway you did a great job, but if you can do a few changes in your code, that would bee great, make sure you use a proper naming convention for creating a class name and function name likewise and better you practice more in w3schools, thank you.